# Download file idempotently with ansible's get_url

Tags: ansible

I want to download a binary idempotently using the `get_url` module.

```yaml
- name: calculate hash for existing file
  stat:
    path: /usr/bin/yq
    checksum_algorithm: sha256
  register: resultStat

- name: (re)download file
  become: true
  get_url:
    url: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/download/v4.34.1/yq_linux_amd64
    #url: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/latest/download/yq_linux_amd64
    dest: /usr/bin/yq
    checksum: "{{ '' if not resultStat.stat.exists else 'sha256:' + resultStat.stat.checksum }}"
    #force: true
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0755'
```

The first time I run that, it works. It also works idempotently when I run it again.

But suppose the remote file is updated - that can be simulated by commenting the line with `v4.34.1` and uncommenting the next line with `latest` (the line with latest is the actual download link that I'll keep in my playbook).

When run again, I expect it to delete the old file and download the new version. This is what it says in [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html#parameter-checksum):

> Additionally, if a checksum is passed to this parameter, and the file exist under the dest location, the destination_checksum would be calculated, and if checksum equals destination_checksum, the file download would be skipped (unless force is true). If the checksum does not equal destination_checksum, the destination file is deleted.

When I use `force: true`, it deletes the old file, then fails with `The checksum for /usr/bin/yq did not match ...`. When I remove `force: true` then it doesn't update the file at all.

How do I do this?

Comment: The main point of making the *url* task idempotent is to avoid the download if the file has already been downloaded. By setting `force: true` you ask *url* to always download the file. Is this really what you want? Don't you want to keep the default `force: false` instead?

Comment: @VladimirBotka I agree that makes sense, and it's how I had it initially. But I tried it with and without, and get the same result (no update). I've updated the question to mention what happens when I remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"If the remote file is updated ... download the new version."***

A: The [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html#parameter-checksum) says:

> ... if a checksum is passed to this parameter, and the file exists under the dest location, the destination_checksum would be calculated, and if checksum equals destination_checksum, the file download would be skipped.

In your code, you calculate the checksum from the existing file under the dest location. Then, in the *url* task, you test this checksum against the same file. This will always match and you will never download the new version.

To solve this problem you have to download the checksum. For example, the below code

```yaml
    - block:

        - file:
            state: directory
            dest: /tmp/ansible/checksums/mikefarah_yq

        - get_url:
            url: "https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/latest/download/{{ item }}"
            dest: "/tmp/ansible/checksums/mikefarah_yq/{{ item }}"
          loop:
            - checksums
            - checksums_hashes_order
            - extract-checksum.sh

        - command:
            cmd: bash extract-checksum.sh SHA-256 yq_linux_amd64
            chdir: /tmp/ansible/checksums/mikefarah_yq
          register: out

        - set_fact:
            yq_linux_amd64_sha256: "sha256:{{ out.stdout|split()|last }}"

        - debug:
            var: yq_linux_amd64_sha256

      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

creates the variable *yq_linux_amd64_sha256*

```yaml
 yq_linux_amd64_sha256: sha256:1952f93323e871700325a70610d2b33bafae5fe68e6eb4aec0621214f39a4c1e
```

Use it in the *get_url* task

```yaml
    - get_url:
        url: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/latest/download/yq_linux_amd64
        dest: /tmp/ansible/checksums/mikefarah_yq/yq
        checksum: "{{ yq_linux_amd64_sha256 }}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - block:

        - file:
            state: directory
            dest: /tmp/ansible/checksums/mikefarah_yq

        - get_url:
            url: "https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/latest/download/{{ item }}"
            dest: "/tmp/ansible/checksums/mikefarah_yq/{{ item }}"
          loop:
            - checksums
            - checksums_hashes_order
            - extract-checksum.sh
          when: download_checksum|d(false)|bool

        - command:
            cmd: bash extract-checksum.sh SHA-256 yq_linux_amd64
            chdir: /tmp/ansible/checksums/mikefarah_yq
          register: out

        - set_fact:
            yq_linux_amd64_sha256: "sha256:{{ out.stdout|split()|last }}"

        - debug:
            var: yq_linux_amd64_sha256

      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - get_url:
        url: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/latest/download/yq_linux_amd64
        dest: /tmp/ansible/checksums/mikefarah_yq/yq
        checksum: "{{ yq_linux_amd64_sha256 }}"
```

---

**The parameter *dest* must contain a filename to avoid the download**

It is good to understand that [despite the matching checksum, the file will be downloaded if *dest* is a directory](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/73185). The module doesn't make the effort to get the filename from the parameter *url*. Quoting from [*dest*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html#parameter-dest):

> If dest is a directory, the file will always be downloaded (regardless of the force and checksum option) but replaced only if the contents changed.

For example, if you omit *yq*

```yaml
        dest: /tmp/ansible/checksums/mikefarah_yq
```

the task shows (-vvv) the file was downloaded

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  checksum_dest: 47d2f3bb48f67374f9aea675e0523b917005870b
  checksum_src: 47d2f3bb48f67374f9aea675e0523b917005870b
  dest: /tmp/ansible/checksums/mikefarah_yq/yq_linux_amd64
  elapsed: 2
  ...
  msg: OK (8949760 bytes)
  src: /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1691044303.5315526-556369-55226723902089/tmp_t3egzzh
```

If you include the filename

```yaml
        dest: /tmp/ansible/checksums/mikefarah_yq/yq
```

the checksum is tested and if matched the file is not downloaded

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => changed=false
  checksum_dest: null
  checksum_src: null
  dest: /tmp/ansible/checksums/mikefarah_yq/yq
  elapsed: 0
  ...
  msg: file already exists
```

Comment: I completely misread the docs... I confused the destination and remote files and checked the wrong one! (I assumed the opposite of what it's actually doing - I thought it would download the file and calculate its checksum then compare to my original checksum.) :-) Your solution is great, thanks.

Comment: I guess the way it actually works makes more sense when you consider that it could be costly to download a 100MiB file to calculate the checksum, and then discover it was a waste of time and bandwidth. So to supply the checksum yourself, is sensible.

Comment: I added the section `The parameter dest must contain a filename to avoid the download`.

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue you specified, where the file is not updated when the remote file is changed, we can make the following modification:

```
- name: calculate hash for existing file
  stat:
    path: /usr/bin/yq
    checksum_algorithm: sha256
  register: resultStat

- name: (re)download file
  become: true
  get_url:
    url: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/latest/download/yq_linux_amd64
    dest: /usr/bin/yq
    checksum: "{{ 'sha256:' + resultStat.stat.checksum if resultStat.stat.exists else None }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0755'
  when: resultStat.stat.exists and resultStat.stat.checksum != 'sha256:EXPECTED_CHECKSUM'
```